# View with variables in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, variables, view, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPmyadmin to create and look at views. I want to have views that take in a variable so I can use different values without creating a new query.

Here is an example of when I would use this.

If I have a query that is looking for people under a certain age:

```
SELECT Name FROM tbl_people
WHERE age < 30;
```

Is there a way to make the value (30) dynamic so that I can change it on the fly? I am thinking that phpmyadmin would prompt for a value before displaying the view, or there could be an input box to change the value.

Not sure if this is even possible but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With phpMyAdmin, if the "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" is activated, you have access to create a bookmark, which is a query that can take a parameter. This query could do a SELECT from a view.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible with a 'View'

You need a [MySql procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) and then call it as a query in phpmyadmin.. something like:

```
CALL peopleByAge(30);
```

I'm not sure if there's something like a plugin or something to call a store procedure in phpmyadmin using an HTML form

Hope this helps